# How to Calculate the Answer With a List

Tags: python-3.x, math

I have a function in my program that
when given list like so: ["23", "+", "25", "/", "5"]. 
My function converts all the numbers that are in the form of a string into an integer which in the end I am left with this list: [23, "+", 25, "/", 5].
My Problem is that with this list I must be able to use the BODMAS rule and calculate the answer of the problem which in this case would be 28 not 9.6.
Note: You don't need to worry about the brackets or of.
Here is my code up until now.

```
op_and_num_list = ["10", "+", "16", "/", "5", "*", "4"]
print(op_and_num_list)

def calculate_list(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        try:
            list[i] = int(list[i])
        except:
            pass

    return list

op_and_num_list = calculate_list(op_and_num_list)
print(op_and_num_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate a list of operations, convert it into a string and apply the `eval()` function

```
op_and_num_list = ["10", "+", "16", "/", "5", "*", "4"]
op = ' '.join(op_and_num_list)
print(eval(op))
```

In the case of `["23", "+", "25", "/", "5"]`, an output of `28.0` would be received.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, kindly accept it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a trick that you don't need to convert string-number to number as above and still get the correct answer:

```
import subprocess
cal = ['10', '+', '16', '/', '5', '*', '4']
cal = ''.join(cal)
output = subprocess.Popen(f"python -c 'print({cal})'", shell=True,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
```

The output will be `'22.8\n'`

Comment: Thanks Binh for the solution and could you just explain to me how this code runs in the background. Thank You.

Comment: Hey Binh I tried your code but It seems that the program is not Showing me the output. If that is the natural behavior then please tell me how I can return or print the output that I the code got. Each time its only showing me either None or puts a blank space and stops the code.Thanks.

Comment: I actually just tell python to calculate "10+16/5*4" for me, it's like when you open the command line, then enter "python" and then "print(1+2+3)", it will show the answer is 6. I basically just get the output string return from the print function, that's why they have "\n" in the end. Hope you understand it